# Data partition on known and unknown rows

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataset with known and unknown variables (just one column). I'd like to separate rows for 2 lists - First list of rows with all known variables and the Second list of rows with all missed (unknown) variables.

```
df = {'Id' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'First' : [30, 22, 18, 49, 22],
     'Second' : [80, 28, 16, 56, 30],
     'Third' : [14, None, None, 30, 27],
     'Fourth' : [14, 85, 17, 22, 14],
     'Fifth' : [22, 33, 45, 72, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Id', 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'])
df
```

Two separate lists with all Known variables and another one with Unknown variables

Comment: Could you please elaborate about this or show the expected answer !!

Comment: list1_known_data:

Id First Second Third Fourth
1 30 80 14.0 14
4 49 56 30.0 22
5 22 30 27.0 14
List2_unknown_data:

Id First Second Third Fourth
2 22 28 NaN 85
3 18 16 NaN 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this helps :

```
df['TF']= df.isnull().any(axis=1)


df_without_none  = df[df['TF'] == 0]
df_with_none  = df[df['TF'] == 1]


print(df_without_none.head())
print(df_with_none.head())


#### Input ####

   Id  First  Second  Third  Fourth  Fruit Total     TF
0   1     30      80   14.0      14        124.0  False
1   2     22      28    NaN      85         50.0   True
2   3     18      16    NaN      17         34.0   True
3   4     49      56   30.0      22        135.0  False
4   5     22      30   27.0      14         79.0  False

#### Output ####

   Id  First  Second  Third  Fourth  Fruit Total     TF
0   1     30      80   14.0      14        124.0  False
3   4     49      56   30.0      22        135.0  False
4   5     22      30   27.0      14         79.0  False
   Id  First  Second  Third  Fourth  Fruit Total    TF
1   2     22      28    NaN      85         50.0  True
2   3     18      16    NaN      17         34.0  True
```